# Which type should I use here? What data is this snapshot is capturing?

Tags: flutter, dart, typeerror

I am unable to understand which circles data type I should change.
This is solved by checking null safety, but any other way to do this

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Stack(
        children: [
          StreamBuilder<List<Circle>>(
            initialData: [],
            stream: _circle$.map((event) => event.length > 100
                ? event.getRange(event.length - 100, event.length).toList()
                : event),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              final circles = snapshot.data;
              return CustomPaint(
                size: size,
                painter: CirclePainter(circles: circles),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to Null-Safety not directly to the data type.

After Null-Safety, every type become has two types, a Nullable Type, which accepts a value or null and marked with a question mark at the end `?`, and a Non-Nullable Type which accepts only a value and not null.

Your problem is that you are trying to pass a Nullable `List<Circle>?` to a Non-Nullable `List<Circle>` which is not allowed because the Nullable Type might contain a `null` value which is not accepted by the Non-Nullable Type while the vice versa is a accepted.

The solution is to check the value of `circles` and to make sure it is not `null`, this approach is called Type Promotion, you can do that by make a loading according to `snapshot.connectionState` and then use the bang operator `!` to till Dart that you are sure the value is not null like the following `circles!`

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `List<Circles>?` and `List<Circles>` is that the first one is nullable. This is because you have **null safety** in Dart.

With it, variables cannot be null if they haven't got a `?` at the end.

You can use a null check `!` as:

```
CirclePainter(circles: circles!) //If circles is null, an Exception will be thrown.
```

or use a ternary operator

```
CirclePainter(circles: circles ?? []) //If circles is null, an empty List will be returned
```